# Incorrect number of bindings in Python Sqlite3 executemany

Tags: python, sqlite, executemany

So I have an sqlite3 database in Python where is a table to which I am trying to add 1000 strings. The problem is, when I use executemany command I get an error

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 1000 supplied.

Here is my code simplified:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("service.db")
db.isolation_level = None
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE Places (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")

toBeAdded = [0]*1000
i = 0
while i < 1000:
    toBeAdded[i] = ("P"+str(i+1))
    i += 1

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Places(name) VALUES (?)",[toBeAdded])
```

I have also tried different forms of that last command, but no luck. This was the only way I could find on Google to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided a flat list to `executemany`. Instead, the method expects a nested structure, with each inner sequence representing a set of parameters to be added to the query.

So, you want `['P0', 'P1', 'P2', ...]` to be `[['P0'], ['P1'], ['P2'], ...]`. You can fix that by adding square brackets while creating your list, to make it nested:

```
toBeAdded = [0]*1000
i = 0
while i < 1000:
    toBeAdded[i] = [("P"+str(i+1))] # Note the surrounding square brackets
    i += 1
```

---

**Additional feedback**

A better way to generate your data would be to use a `for` loop and get rid of the `while` loop - you have a pre-determined number of iterations to perform, so it's idiomatic to use a `for`. You also don't need to initialise the list beforehand.

```
to_be_added = []
for i in range(1000):
    to_be_added.append([("P"+str(i+1))])
```

Or, using a *list comprehension*:

```
to_be_added = [[("P"+str(x+1))] for x in range(1000)]
```

You'll note that I've removed the camelCase from the variable name; this is in line with the Python style guide - [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)